# JavaScript - is it possible to force code execution after an error?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a PoC of reflected Cross-Site Scripting on a website that I'm testing right now. I've found a place inside of a Javascript code where commands can be injected, however the trouble is that there the previous block of code throws a 'not defined' error  and therefore (at least I think so) my injected code is not executed. Is there any chance to execute the code anyway?

Here is the code:

```
UndefinedObject.Init({
  Var1:"a",
  Var2:"b",
  Var3:"can_be_injected_with_JS_code")}
```

I can't inject any HTML tags as these are filtered by the application.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can try to use the event 'onerror'. Althought it's main task for image tags, try that to continue to execute the code.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I've tried to bound the onerror event to 'window' and 'UndefinedObject', haven't have any luck so far, though.

Comment: Compare to try and catch you can't bind this event to a specific exception. This has more general effect. For more information see http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error.shtml .

Comment: Thank you for the link. If I understand the information correctly, the onerror event is not usable for me as well as I would have to define it before the code throwing the error. In my case, I'm able to inject my code only after the erroneous piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them under try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

In a sequence of execution, if the code fails, the remaining part will not be executed. Javascript errors ("Exceptions") can be caught using [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) (if you are able to inject this try - catch also).

If there is a different flow (via another event), the code will continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try using a try-catch, or if that won't help, try using `window.onerror`

Answer (score 1):

Generally the right way of doing that is using *try-catch-finally* or *try-finally*:

If you make something about the error - log or do something else. Catch may be also used to execute your code, but not a good practice. You can do nothing about the error if you want, that`s why *finally* is used.

*Finally* is used when it is important to execute a piece of code, no matter if an error is thrown or not. For example in C++ or other language when you work with files inside *finally* the file is closed ( you can not leave it opened ). Look [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml) for some examples.

Comment: I'm familiar with try/catch/finally, but as far as I know, I'd have to be able to place the try statement BEFORE the UndefinedObject.Init method which is unfortunately not the case here, I'm able to inject the code as late as by the Var3 variable.